# Attempting to read from SD card throws UnauthorizedAccessException

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-permissions

I'm building an Android app with Xamarin and need to allow users to select a JPEG image from their device and upload it. The process spans a few different classes and involves a lot of checks which I'll exclude here, but this is the gist of it:

```
private void ChooseImage()
{
  // Open the image picker
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionGetContent);
  intent.SetType("image/jpg");
  _activity.StartActivityForResult(intent, (int)ImageRequest.ChooseImage);
}

protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
{
  base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  string path;

  Android.Net.Uri selectedImage = data.Data;
  string[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.MediaColumns.Data, MediaStore.MediaColumns.DisplayName };

  using (ICursor cursor = ContentResolver.Query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null))
  {
    // Get the path to the selected file
    path = cursor.GetString(columnIndex);
  }

  using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
  {
    byte[] bytes = new byte[fs.Length];

    // This throws an UnauthorizedAccessException
    fs.Read(bytes, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

    UploadImage(bytes);
  }
}
```

I also have the necessary permissions set in AndroidManifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

This code causes the following exception to be thrown if the user chooses an image on the SD card rather than the local storage:

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/storage/sdcard1/[user selected image].jpg" is denied.`

So...
**Why do I not have permission to read from the SD card?**

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746787/xamarin-android-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-is-de can help you.

Comment: Thanks - it turned out my issue was just down to opening the stream in ReadWrite mode rather than Read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was caused by this line:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
```

I should have added the third argument to specify Read mode rather than the default Read/Write:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
```