# UnauthorizedAccessException on Xamarin.Android on some files

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I have some files in the `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal` folder, say A and B for simplicity.

File A was created by the app, while file B was copied in via Android Studio's Device File Explorer.
The app can open A, but B throws an `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

To open, after checking whether the `File.Exists`, I use

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None);
```

`File.Exists` correctly returns that the files exists, but creating the `new FileStream` fails for B.

I have already tried changing the user/group of the B file, as well as changing the permissions to match the info from file A.

I am debugging this in an Android emulator with version 7.1.1 API level 25.

How can I solve the problem, or at least find more information about the problem?

Edit: I've tried a 8.1 API level 27 with no success, but on a physical device LG D618 with 5.0 API 21 it works.

How can I make the emulator work?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is that you need to ask the permission at runtime.

According to the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting):

> You declare that your app needs a permission by listing the permission in the app manifest and then requesting that the user approve each permission at runtime (on Android 6.0 and higher).

You physical device is running on Android 5.0, so it works fine.

You could refer to this [blog](https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) for how to do it in xamarin.

Comment: I have both the permissions listed in the manifest and ask the user for the permissions. Now I've found that some of the copied files open and some don't. I think that the problem might be the files somehow, but do not know what could be causing it...

Comment: @NathanOliveira Hope [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746787/xamarin-android-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-is-de) may help.