# unauthorized access exception - access to the path denied - API29

Tags: xamarin, onedrive

I got access to .txt file located on OneDrive by changing it's path end from =***** to =download. Then I'm trying to download this file using the following code:

```
            string fileName = Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads + "/textfile.txt";
            WebClient web = new WebClient();
            web.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            web.Proxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            web.DownloadFile(uslugiPath, fileName);
```

As a result I get this Unauthorized.Access exception (access to Downloads is denied).

I checked [This] ([Xamarin : Android : System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746787/xamarin-android-system-unauthorizedaccessexception-access-to-the-path-is-de?noredirect=1&lq=1)) topic and many others but I didn't find solution.

Permissins.CheckStatusAsync<Permissions.StorageREad> as a result gives "Granted".

API 29

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in my case the solution was use the path defined

`var fileName = global::Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath`

Comment: You can mark this answer which will help more people with same problem:).